# Program that copies the content of one file, pastes it to another with a transformation (IO Error appearing)

Tags: python, ios, exception

I have a text file 'index.txt' with the following words 'dog cat' and another text file 'dog' with the following content: "This is the file dog’s content!"

I'm asked to write a program that:

-Asks the user for the name of the file containing the file names

-Opens that file, and process it line by line

-For each line, it should open the first file for reading, and the second for writing, and write the required data to the second.

-Finally, close each file when it is finished with it.

And so a run of the program should be:

-Please enter the name of the file: index

...This program should now create a file 'cat' with the exact same content as 'dog', but all the capital letters should be changed to lower case and all non-letter characters (such as '.', and '!') should be removed.

This is my code so far:

```
s = input("Enter a file name: ")+".txt"

try: f = open(s, 'r') 
     string = open(s, 'r').read() 
     names = string.split()

     g = open(names[0]+".txt", 'r') 
     h = open(names[1], "w")

for line in g:
    s = ""
    for ch in line:
        if ch.isalpha() or ch==" ":
            ch = ch.lower()
            s += ch
    h.write(s+"\n")



    h.close()
    g.close()
    f.close()
except IOError: 
    print("Some form of IO error") 
except FileNotFoundError: 
    print("File does not exist") 
except PermissionError: 
    print("A permission error")
```

And when I run the program it keeps showing me an IO error. I've put the index file, dog file and the python program file all in the same folder, and I can't figure out how to fix the IO error. Or is there something wrong with the code?

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `h = open(names[1], "w")`, `names[1]` has the correct file name with the `.txt` appended to it ? if you really want to find out what's wrong edit `except IOError:` to be `except IOError as e: print(e)`